# Send a $_GET request with special characters in the HTTP header (escaping)

Tags: php, get, wordpress, http-headers, escaping

I'm trying to work on my new wordpress plugin, and I encountered an issue.
I'm setting a variable to contain something like this:
esc_html('likeit'.wp_generate_password(4))

And then - I want to call another function via GET, but it's sometimes breaking.
For example if I have: likeitA9&n, it will break at &.

Can you please tell me what's the best (and most secured) but simple way to handle this in my plugin?
Examples would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

P.S. - I did try to look at previous posts, but nothing that actually solved this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
urlencode('likeit'.wp_generate_password(4));
```

or

```
rawurlencode('likeit'.wp_generate_password(4));
```